# Sequel one_to_one association

Tags: ruby, sequel

Referencing [Sequel's docs](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/association_basics.rdoc#one_to_many-and-one_to_one) I've set up a `one_to_one` association between a Position and a Company.

```ruby
class Position < Sequel::Model
  one_to_one :company
end
class Company < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :position
end
```

When I try to get a company through a position I get nil, although I can find the company with a direct Sequel query.

```ruby
p = Position.first #=> #<Position @values={:id=>1}>
p.company #=> nil
Company.where(position_id: p.id).first #=> #<Company @values={:id=>1, position_id: 1}>
```

Comment: I think you have that backwards and wrong. (a) I would expect that a company would have a `one_to_many` relationship with positions. (One company has many positions available, right?) (b) If model A has a `one_to_many` relationship with model B, then model B should have a `many_to_one` relationship with model A, not a `one_to_one`. Perhaps you had best describe what data you are trying to model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look confused about the relations or the schema. Unless you have a very specific business case, a company has many positions, which makes one-to-many relation and many positions can belong to one company, which makes many-to-one.

Here's how I see it:

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://companies')

DB.create_table :companies do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
end
DB[:companies].insert(name: 'Acme')

DB.create_table :positions do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  foreign_key :company_id, :companies
end
DB[:positions].insert(name: 'CEO', company_id: DB[:companies].first[:id])
DB[:positions].insert(name: 'CTO', company_id: DB[:companies].first[:id])

class Company < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :positions
end

class Position < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :company
end

p Company.first.positions
# [#<Position @values={:id=>1, :name=>"CEO", :company_id=>1}>, #<Position @values={:id=>2, :name=>"CTO", :company_id=>1}>]

p Position.first.company
# #<Company @values={:id=>1, :name=>"Acme"}>
```

Comment: **Unless you have a very specific business case, a company has many positions, which makes one-to-many relation and many positions can belong to one company,**  O RLY. So no two companies can have the same position, e.g accountant?

Comment: @7stud I thought of position as a particular job offer, not as an occupation in general. You are right though, it was only my assumption I and should not have to make such an unconditional claim. But it seems my assumption was right for the OP, because he accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

I can get your associations to work:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://test.db')

unless DB.table_exists? (:positions)
  DB.create_table :positions do
    primary_key :id
    string      :name
    foreign_key :company_id
  end
end

unless DB.table_exists?(:companies)
  DB.create_table :companies do
    primary_key :id
    string      :name
    foreign_key :position_id
  end
end

class Position < Sequel::Model
  one_to_one :company 
end

class Company < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :position 
end

ford = Company.create(name: "Ford")
vw = Company.create(name: "VW")

accountant.company = ford
p accountant.company  #=> #<Company @values={:id=>53, :name=>"Ford", :position_id=>35}>
puts accountant.id    #=> 35

accountant.add_company(vw)  #=> undefined method `add_company' for #<Position...
```

I'll add that the Sequel docs for associations are terrible. They need to include a complete example--including how to create the objects so that they are associated with each other.

Comment: From what you wrote below my answer, you should have made a reference table, i.e. `company_positions`, leaving companies and positions without foreign keys, and thus making both relations many-to-many. Or what was you trying to achieve? Relations in OP's example are contradictory. You can technically have one-to-one from one side and many-to-one from other like OP stated, but it won't make any sense, unless you have a specific business case, but judging from names of the associations, it isn't.